# C - Last Captured Data Item Not Written To File

Tags: c

My program is supposed to capture three items of data for a student and write them to a file; ID, Name and Course.

Name and Course contain spaces.
It runs, but when I check the file only ID and Name are written. Is it because of how I'm capturing the data?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct StudentDetails{
    char ID[50];
    char Name[50];
    char Course[50];
}aStudent; 

void capture(){
    char ch;

    printf("Enter ID: ");
    scanf ("%s", &aStudent.ID);

    printf("Enter Name: ");
    scanf ("%s ", &aStudent.Name);

    printf("Enter Course: ");
    scanf ("%s ", &aStudent.Course);
    ch = getchar();

}
void saveToFile(){
    FILE *studentDetails;
    studentDetails =  fopen("students.txt", "a");

    fprintf(studentDetails,"%s\t%s\t%s\n",aStudent.ID, aStudent.Name,aStudent.Course);
    fclose(studentDetails);
}

void main(){
    capture();
    saveToFile();
}
```

Comment: You might want to increase the compiler's warning level (for GCC pass `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`), read and understand the warning(s) issued during compilation, then fix the code until no more warnings are given any more. Do not blindly cast away warning(d).

Comment: Where do I place this code aStudent.ID[strcspn(aStudent.ID,"\n")]=0

Answer (score 0):

First off, a quick note on how scanf works: Whenever scanf is called it skips leading white spaces, reads and stores characters until it encounters white space again (and "space" is a white space character). As soon as it encounters a white space character it returns and considers the remaining characters when its called again.

Now, looking at your program, I am assuming ID doesn't contain any white spaces so gets consumed by scanf completely but when your programs is ready to accept Name and say you enter "James Bond". This string contains a white space therefore scanf stores "James" in &aStudent.Name and returns. As mentioned, "Bond" gets stored when scanf is called next, therefore &aStudent.Course gets to store Bond. So your program never gets a chance to store Course. Hence the result.

Comment: Yes, ID has no whitespaces. That explains a lot .Would i use fgets instead like the above comment suggests? I thought that was for reading from a file? Also how then would that line look like?

Comment: As advised above, just use STDIN as file stream in fgets() and it will work like a charm and it's safe as well.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again. May I please have the line of code that starts with fgets. I can't see it anymore here and I lost my program with it